# Паттерн Registry (Реестр)

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, реестр

Не могу найти понятного описания паттерна `Registry`... Была бы благодарна за ссылку на (желательно русскоязычную) статью, понятно описывающие этот паттерн (желательно на джаве и с примером из жизни), или же за Ваш пример с кодом.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа.

Comment: Мы не знаем, почему одно описание понятно, а другое нет. Без этого понимания можно только кидать ссылки наугад, пока вдруг не попадётся понятная статья. Поэтому вопрос стоит закрыть. А вот если вы бы описали, что из прочитанного непонятно - как применить к такому-то кейсу или зачем нужно то-то в реализации - был бы конкретный вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/registry.html

> Хорошо известный объект, который используется другими объектами для получения общих объектов и сервисов.
>
> Когда нужно найти какой-нибудь объект, обычно начинают с другого объекта, связанного с целевым. Например, если нужно найти все счета для покупателя, начинают, как раз с покупателя и используют его метод получения счетов. Тем не менее, в некоторых случаях нет подходящего объекта, с которого начать. Например, известен ID покупателя, но нет ссылки на него. Тогда нужен своего рода объект-поисковик, но тогда возникает вопрос - как вы найдёте сам поисковик?
>
> Реестр (Registry) - это глобальный объект по сути своей или, по крайней мере, так выглядит - он может функционировать только будучи глобальным.

Банальнейший пример из жизни - БД с настройками. Этот объект

- глобальный
- может вернуть конкретный параметр
- может сохранять параметр

Сделайте обвязку всего этого в класс и получите объект `Registry`